# Python, ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension issue

Tags: python, numpy, csv

Im trying to read in a CSV file and plot that but when i try and plot the y variable it says there are only two elements to that variable when there should in fact be 6, the code is as followed:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
y1=[]
y2=[]

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
plots= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in plots:
    y1.append(int(row[1]))
print(len(y1))


with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
plots= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in plots:
    y2.append(int(row[2]))
print(len(y2))
```

This produces 2,2 which is the issue, it should be producing 6,6 as there are 6 elements to both? the CSV file is set in the following format:
Dishwasher,1,1,1,1,1,1

Washing Machine,1,1,0,1,1,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It produces 2,2 because there are 2 `row`s in `plots`. Essentially you are storing the second column in y1 and the third column in y2.

If that is what you want then your code is fine, if you want to measure row lengths instead you could use this code:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    rows = [row for row in plots]
    print(len(rows[0]) - 1)  # -1 to exclude title
    print(len(rows[1]) - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. How would i attribute each row to a variable then? Since im plotting multiple lines.

Comment: Do `y1 = rows[0]` and `y2 = rows[1]`, or just use `rows[0]`/`rows[1]` directly